# Mongolab connection error

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I'm getting the following message when I try connecting to MongoLab with the command:

mongo ds035438.mongolab.com:35438/comeventsbw -u (myusername) -p (mypassword)

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: ds035438.mongolab.com:35438/comeventsbw
2015-12-10T10:30:18.537-0700 I STORAGE  In File::open(), ::open for '/Users/benwong/.mongorc.js' failed with errno:13 Permission denied
The ".mongorc.js" file located in your home folder could not be executed

Comment: Does the `~/.mongorc.js` file exist?

Comment: yes it does cause I tried recreating .mongorc.js using sublime and overwrite it and it alerts me that it exists already. I tried doing sudo with the command and it works now. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to delete the root directory `.mongorc.js` file. To do this in mac OS you can use `cd ~/&&ls -al`, if you see `.mongorc.js` that is owned by root, so we can use `sudo rm .mongorc.js` to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in Ubuntu-18. Initially I logged in as normal user. I typed **mongo** on the terminal. So I got same above error. So I switched to the root user using **sudo -s**     This time when I typed **mongo** command on the terminal I'm able to connect mongo server. So I thought this service is not available for the normal user.