# Failed to connect mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

when i tired to connect mongodb server i got that error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
2017-06-08T12:14:38.297+0300 I STORAGE  [main] In File::open(), ::open for '/Users/ofekseroussi/.mongorc.js' failed with Permission denied
The ".mongorc.js" file located in your home folder could not be executed
```

How do I fix it.?
thank you !

Comment: See [Mongolab connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208373/mongolab-connection-error)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the `.mongorc.js` file and the problem would be solved. To do this in macOS you can use `cd ~/&&ls -al`, if you see `.mongorc.js` that is owned by the root user, so you can use `sudo rm .mongorc.js` to delete it.