# Mongodb connection error when exec in kubernetes pod

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed mongodb using Helm chart with following values:

```
mongodb:
  mongodbUsername: mongo_user
  mongodbPassword: verylongpassword
  mongodbDatabase: mongo_read_db
  replicaCount: 1
```

But when I `exec` into the pod by:

`kubectl exec -it pod sh`

And give
`$mongo` command, I get the following error

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("5d2a9b35d-4ef1-4eeeb0-8fee2-ac9974e7ee66a") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.2
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
2020-02-03T13:29:07.716+0000 I  STORAGE  [main] In File::open(), ::open for '//.mongorc.js' failed with Permission denied
```

I tried this after I am unable to connect from rails app.

Comment: Can you run `whoami && ls -l mongorc.js` ?

Comment: I meant of course `.mongorc.js` mentioned in the error message.

Comment: After `kubectl exec -it pod sh` type `cd` and then `mongo` and see if you are getting the same error. (I am changing the current working directory to home of the user will have access)

Comment: @Tek Nath, did you manage to solve your issue ? Did you change permissions of `.mongorc.js` file ?

Comment: @mario The above error keeps on coming but was able to connect and create databases after changing the mongodb uri.

Comment: You can try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784197/11714114) workaround to get rid of this error.